# Issue in byte array to String conversion

Tags: android, arrays, string, hex, data-conversion

I'am trying to convert the byte array to HEX String. Below is my byte to string conversion method,

```
public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexArray = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j*2] = hexArray[v/16];
        hexChars[j*2 + 1] = hexArray[v%16];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

The issue is, the data what sender is sending is something like this

> 00 4A 60 01 02 03 04 02 10 30 38 00 00 0E **80** 02
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 31 00 00 46 74 16 54 28
> 12 11 38 33 34 35 31 36 30 30 34 36 37 34 31 36
> 35 34 32 39 30 30 36 32 37 30 35 35 32 34 00 12
> **91** 0A 59 21 8C DA FB BC D2 52 00 14

and what I'm getting after conversion is something like this

> 00 4A 60 01 02 03 04 02 10 30 38 00 00 0E **EF BF**
> **BD** 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 31 00 00 46 74 16
> 54 28 12 11 38 33 34 35 31 36 30 30 34 36 37 34
> 31 36 35 34 32 39 30 30 36 32 37 30 35 35 32 34
> 00 12 **EF BF BD**

while most of the data is similar, but "EFBFBD" data is coming somehow.

Here's the same bytes again but as a hexdump with helpful colors: **Before conversion:**
[image: 1.hexdump-before-conversion]
**After conversion:**
[image: 2.hexdump-after-conversion]

**UPDATE**

The complete code required for assessment of problem:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

public class TCPClient {

private static final String TAG = "TCPRequest";

public static final String SERVER_IP = "X.X.X.X"; //server IP address
public static final int SERVER_PORT = xxxx;

private String mServerMessage;
// sends message received notifications
private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
// while this is true, the server will continue running
private boolean mRun = false;
// used to send messages
private OutputStream mOutStream;

private InputStream mInStream;

// used to read messages from the server
private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

byte[] bMsg = new byte[100];
int byteArr;

/**
 * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
 */
public TCPClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 *
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(final String message) {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (mOutStream != null) {
                try {

                    byte[] bMessage = BytesUtil.hexStringToByteArray(message);
                    mOutStream.write(bMessage, 0, bMessage.length);
                    mOutStream.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
}

/**
 * Close the connection and release the members
 */
public void stopClient() throws IOException {

    mRun = false;

    if (mOutStream != null) {
        mOutStream.flush();
        mOutStream.close();
    }

    mMessageListener = null;
    mServerMessage = null;

    mOutStream = null;
    mInStream = null;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        PrintLog.log("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        //Socket socket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT);
        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT), 100000);

        sendMessage("requestData");

        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            PrintLog.log("CONNECTED...");
        } else {
            PrintLog.log("NOT CONNECTED: ");
        }

        try {

            //sends the message to the server
            mOutStream = socket.getOutputStream();

            //receives the message which the server sends back
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {

                bMsg = mBufferIn.readLine().getBytes();
                
                PrintLog.log(TAG, "Byte Array Response (Local): " + toHexString(bMsg));

                mServerMessage = new String(bMsg);
                
                PrintLog.log(TAG, "Listening message...");
                if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                }
            }

            PrintLog.log("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + String.valueOf(mServerMessage) + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            PrintLog.log("TCP", "S: Error" + e);
        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        PrintLog.log("TCP", "C: Error" + e);
    }

}

public static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexArray = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j*2] = hexArray[v/16];
        hexChars[j*2 + 1] = hexArray[v%16];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}

//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the Activity
//class at on AsyncTask doInBackground
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);
}

static String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

}

Please help me solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you have posted seems to be OK. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Updated the complete source code.

Comment: EF BF BD sounds very close to the utf-8 bom mark of EF BB BF

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I resolved the issue by receiving data using "InputStream" rather than "BufferedReader". I guess those junk characters was because of nextLine().

Answer (score 0):

`String` and `char` (2 bytes UTF-16) hold Unicode **text** (by language design). Hence a conversion between `byte[]` - **binary data** - and `String` always involves an encoding and a possibly corrupting or failing conversion.

The above could possibly be corrected with a single-byte encoding like Latin-1:

```
new String(hexChars, "ISO-8859-1");
```

However it takes twice the memory (char is 2 bytes), is principly slower (converting the bytes) and unsafe.

Your version takes the default platform encoding, UTF-8, and can run into unconvertible byte sequences, as UTF-8 is a very strict format.

***The error lies in other code.***

Maybe in a `getBytes` without encoding:

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

Rewriting the code to just stay with `byte[]`/`ByteArrayOutputStream` is best.

---

***After I/O code provided:***

Failing patches would be:

```
        mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));

        bMsg = mBufferIn.readLine().getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
```

The problem is that a very long line might be read, and that the line separator is dropped (CR, LF, NEL).

So the code must be more something vague like:

```
        // receives the message which the server sends back
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(socket.getInputStream(), baos);
        byte[] content = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: @KiranMalvi extended the answer; unfortunately binary data should be handed as non-Strings here.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but using IOUtils only for this conversion will make code heavier, right? Because as I understand IOUtils is very big library.

Comment: Yes, an additional library is probably not needed; hence _"something vague like"_. I do not know the details of the task at hand.

Comment: Thanks for the help, although I resolved the issue by receiving data using "InputStream" rather than "BufferedReader". I guess those junk characters was because of nextLine().